# How to replace a placeholder in a String with a SimpleDateFormat Pattern

Tags: java, apache-commons, spring-el

In a given String like this

```
".../uploads/${customer}/${dateTime('yyyyMMdd')}/report.pdf"
```

I need to replace a `customer` and a `yyyyMMdd` timestamp.

To replace the `customer` placeholder, I could use the `StrSubstitutor` from Apache Commons. But how to replace the `SimpleDateFormat`? We are running in a Spring enviourment, so maybe `Spring EL` is an option?

The markup for the placeholders is not fixed, it is ok if another library needs syntactical changes.

This small tests shows the problem:

```
SimpleDateFormat            formatter   = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

String                      template    = ".../uploads/${customer}/${dateTime('yyyyMMdd')}/report.pdf";

@Test
public void shouldResolvePlaceholder()
{
    final Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<String, String>();
    model.put("customer", "Mr. Foobar");

    final String filledTemplate = StrSubstitutor.replace(this.template, model);

    assertEquals(".../uploads/Mr. Foobar/" + this.formatter.format(new Date()) + "/report.pdf", filledTemplate);
}
```

Comment: is that date part always the last folder in your directory structure?

Comment: No, in some other reports it is in the middle. Or in the filename. This is just an example.

Answer (score 31):

Why don't you use [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) instead?

```
String result = MessageFormat.format(".../uploads/{0}/{1,date,yyyyMMdd}/report.pdf", customer, date);
```

Or with [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
String result = String.format(".../uploads/%1$s/%2$tY%2$tm%2$td/report.pdf", customer, date);
```

Comment: I like they way with named variables. Because the String comes from another module. They don't know in which I use. With the `MessageFormat` I need to communicate Index 0 = customer, 1 = current Date, 2 = ....     hm....

Comment: Isn't the formatting an implementation detail? How it it "exposed" to your customers? Isn't it just a method call with typed parameters?

Answer (score 9):

As NilsH suggested MessageFormat is really nice for this purpose. To have named variables you can hide MessageFormat behind your class:

```
public class FormattedStrSubstitutor {
    public static String formatReplace(Object source, Map<String, String> valueMap) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : valueMap.entrySet()) {   
            String val = entry.getValue();
            if (isPlaceholder(val)) {
                val = getPlaceholderValue(val);
                String newValue = reformat(val);

                entry.setValue(newValue);
            }
        }

        return new StrSubstitutor(valueMap).replace(source);
    }

    private static boolean isPlaceholder(String isPlaceholder) {
        return isPlaceholder.startsWith("${");
    }

    private static String getPlaceholderValue(String val) {
        return val.substring(2, val.length()-1);
    }

    private static String reformat(String format) {
        String result = MessageFormat.format("{0,date," + format + "}", new Date());

        return result;
    }
}
```

And you have to adjust your testcase:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

String template = ".../uploads/${customer}/${dateTime}/report.pdf";

@Test
public void shouldResolvePlaceholder() {
    final Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<String, String>();
    model.put("customer", "Mr. Foobar");
    model.put("dateTime", "${yyyyMMdd}");

    final String filledTemplate = FormattedStrSubstitutor.formatReplace(this.template,
        model);

    assertEquals(".../uploads/Mr. Foobar/" + this.formatter.format(new Date())
        + "/report.pdf", filledTemplate);
}
```

I have removed generics and replace those with String. Also `isPlaceholder` and `getPlaceholderValue` is hardcoded and expect *${value}* syntax.

But this is just just the idea to solve your problem. To do this can use the methods from `StrSubstitutor` (just use is or make `FormattedStrSubstitutor extends StrSubstitutor`).

Also you can use for example *$d{value}* for date formatting and *$foo{value}* for foo formatting.

**UPDATE**

Could not sleep without full solution. You can add this method to `FormattedStrSubstitutor` class:

```
public static String replace(Object source,
        Map<String, String> valueMap) {

    String staticResolved = new StrSubstitutor(valueMap).replace(source);

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\$\\{date)(.*?)(\\})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(staticResolved);

    String dynamicResolved = staticResolved;
    while (m.find()) {
        String result = MessageFormat.format("{0,date" + m.group(2) + "}",
                new Date());

        dynamicResolved = dynamicResolved.replace(m.group(), result);
    }

    return dynamicResolved;
}
```

Your testcase is like in your question (small changes in placeholder):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

String template = ".../uploads/${customer}/${date,yyyyMMdd}/report.pdf";

@Test
public void shouldResolvePlaceholder() {
    final Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<String, String>();
    model.put("customer", "Mr. Foobar");

    final String filledTemplate =  FormattedStrSubstitutor.replace(this.template,
            model);

    assertEquals(
            ".../uploads/Mr. Foobar/" + this.formatter.format(new Date())
                    + "/report.pdf", filledTemplate);
}
```

Same limitation as before; no generics and fix prefix and suffix for placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's as simple as this?

```
static final Pattern DOLLARS = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([^}]+)}");

public static String resolve(String string, Map<String,String> config) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher matcher = DOLLARS.matcher(string);
    int start = 0;
    while (matcher.find(start)) {
        builder.append(string.substring(start, matcher.start()));
        String property = matcher.group(1);
        String value = config.get(property);
        builder.append(value);
        start = matcher.end();
    }
    builder.append(string.substring(start));
    return builder.toString();
}
```